# How to add date to edittext on android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, date, calendar, android-edittext

Hey i have been trying to make a edittext, etDate, that automatically insert the date of the day, but i haven't found anything usefull.

How can i do this?

here is my code, i am trying to make a app to keep track off my run exercises..

Thanks for your help..

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Start extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button bStartTur;
EditText etDate, etKm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    bStartTur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartTur);
    bStartTur.setOnClickListener(this);
    etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
    etKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse("01/01/2012");  


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    Date date;
    etDate.setText(date);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.bStartTur:

        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What are you getting when you run this code?

Comment: where are your setText() methods for the edittext views?
does not look like you have the full code pasted.. add your full code

Comment: Sorry here it is.. This code isn't working..
I don't have any experience with Calender methods yet, therefore i'm a bit lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show date here is code for getting current date

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

now just use setText method of your EditText using the string currentDateandTime .

here is the full code according to your given code.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button bStartTur;
EditText etDate, etKm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start);
bStartTur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartTur);
bStartTur.setOnClickListener(this);
etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
etKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
try {  
     etDate.setText(format.format(new Date()));


} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
// Date date;




}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (v.getId()){

case R.id.bStartTur:

    break;
}

}

}
```